# Extracting rows from training/test set and storing them in a list of 2 elements

Tags: r, dataframe, element

I'm just wondering if anyone can help me figure out this problem I'm having converting my two subsets of data into a dataframe of 2 elements.

I have subsetted my data into a training subset (`train`) which is 2000 x 300 and a testing subset (`test`) which is 500 x 300 and I want to store them both as an element in a dataframe, `dat` (so `dat$train` and `dat$test`).

I tried :

```
dat <- rbind(train, test)
```

then once `dat` was first tried:

```
dat$train <- dat[1:2000,]
dat$test <- dat[2001:2500,]
```

which didn't work and then secondly

```
dat <- data.frame(train = 1:2000, test = 2001:2500)
```

but I got the error that the arguments imply differing number of rows.

What's the best way I can approach this problem, I don't really understand how to extract or label the two submatrices (2000 x 300) and (500 x 300) as specific elements?

Comment: use a `list` ? `dat <- list(train = train, test = test)`  then access data same way, `dat$train`.

Comment: What you were doing is placing them side by side in a single frame, which requires the same length of rows. The list of data frames zacdav suggested is the way to go~

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly!